# how can I make entities enumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I am attempting to join to lists, add them to a viewmodel, and iterate through those lists in the view.

```
IList<trace> traces = db.traces.Where(t => t.bureau_rep == "MGS").Take(20).ToList();

IList<business> businesses = new List<business>();

var joined = from t in traces
    join b in businesses
    on t.businessid equals b.businessid
    select new vwhome { traces = t, business = b };

return View(joined);
```

The view model looks like this...

```
public class vwhome
{
    public trace traces { get; set; }
    public business business { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I would like to display the list of traces, each of which has one business that should be displayed.

- notification 1 business a
- notification 2 business a
- notification 3 business a
- notification 4 business b
- notification 5 business b

My problem is that trace and business are not enumerable, so I can't do this...

```
public class vwhome
{
    public IList<trace> traces { get; set; }
    public business business { get; set; }
}
```

How should I resolve this?

### ------------------------------------

Edit - This is clearly not a good solution, but at least it works...

This is now how I'm filling the viewmodel...

```
IList<trace> traces = db.traces.Where(t => t.bureau_rep == "MGS").Take(20).ToList();

        IList<business> businesses = new List<business>();

        foreach (var item in traces)
        {
            businesses.Add(db.businesses.Find(item.businessid));
        }
        var viewModel = new vwhome();
        viewModel.traces = traces;
        viewModel.business = businesses;
```

And this is my view...

```
@foreach(var item in Model.traces)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.bureau_rep)</td>
        @foreach(var b in Model.business)
        {
            if(b.businessid == item.businessid)
            {
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => b.name)</td>
            }
        }
    </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? `traces.GroupBy(x => x.businessid)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with how the `trace` relates to the `business`. Try working with the relationships between your `trace` and `business` classes. It appears that the `trace` class should have a many-to-one relationship to `business` within your entity models. Not knowing what your models for these classes look like, I recommend that you could make sure you have the appropriate references within the classes. if they aren't there, add these:

Add this to your `trace` class:

```
public virtual business business { get; set; }
```

Add the following to your `business` class:

```
public business()
{
    this.Traces = new List<trace>();
}

public virtual ICollection<trace> Traces { get; set; }
```

And within your `tracemap` class add the relationship:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.business)
   .WithMany(t => t.Traces)
   .HasForeignKey(t => t.businessid);
```

Once you have this setup, try setting up your view model like this:

```
public class vmhome 
{
    public trace trace { get; set; }
    public business business { get; set; }
}
```

and use the relationships in your LINQ query

```
var joined = 
from t in traces select new vwhome 
{ 
    trace = t, 
    business = t.business
};
```

Then in your View, you can run through your references:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.trace.prop_1)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.business.name)
```

You could probably omit the `business` class from the vm and just exploit the relationship in your View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.trace.business.name)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: you're spot on, however, I'm working with a db first edmx. I don't have direct control (without quite a bit more work) over the model classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `traces` and `business` fields need to be strings, not of the actual object, and populate them with the trace name and the business. Then you can pass that along to your view to be property displayed on the screen.

The LINQ query you have near the top will return those as an `IEnumerable<vwhome>`.

Comment: In the view, I need access to the properties of the trace entity. Trace is not a single field. So I can't just cast it as a string I would think...

Comment: In the case of the business, I only need one field - the business name.

Comment: Fine then. Then have your view model only contain those fields that you would need then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you will need this in your Trace class

```
public virtual vwhome vwhome { get; set; }
```

In your vwhome class you need

```
public virtual ICollection<Trace > Traces { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You view is using a *collection* of `vwhome` objects, each of which contains a `trace` and a `vusiness`, so your view will look something like:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@(item.trace) @(item.business)</li>
}
</ul>
```